# I can not install my printer

Tags: printing

I have a Brother DCP-150C Printer. In my prior Ubuntu 14.04.1 installation I installed it by opening the Terminal and running the following: `sudo apt-install brother-lpr-drivers-extra`.

Now, I have a new PC with Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't get my printer to function.

Comment: The printer and Skype are two different problems, reasonably. Can you please add a new question about Skype, change the title of this question, and tell us more about what else you have tried (if anything) to get the printer to work.

Comment: Thank u Gunnar,  however I have tried all this in the past and now again,  but it does not work. It seems as if the PC can interact with the Printer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is:

```
sudo apt-get install brother-lpr-drivers-extra
```

Instead of `apt-get`, you ran `apt-install`, which is not a program.

*Edit:*

You probably also need to install a couple of further .deb files, get fom the [Brother web site](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcp165c_all&os=128).

Comment: Have very dear thanks for u answer,  but sadly this is not working.  In my previose PC I ran Ubuntu 14.04.1 and here this command as I've written it above worked.

Comment: @SebastianC.: Have you downloaded and installed the files from the Brother site I linked to?

Comment: First of all I wish to thank u dearly.                            I just ask myself as to why it worked under UBUNTU 14.04.1 with this command : sudo apt-get install brother-lpr-drivers-extra And that is why I hope if I will upgrade to 14.04.1 that these problems will be solved.  I have upgraded but sadly to 14.10,  and this doesn't help a bit.

Comment: Hi Gunnar, I dearly thank u for u help but as to answer u question,  this website is for a different Printer.  I have DCP-150C and not DCP-165 . In this site my printer is not even listed between all those models that are.

Comment: @SebastianC.: Right, I know it's not the same model. I didn't find your model there either. Ok.. I can't tell if it ought to be sufficient to install `brother-lpr-drivers-extra`. What I do know is that typically, at least, Brother printers need stuff from the Brother site to work. I doubt that the problem is related to the Ubuntu version. But, to be honest, I'm not quite sure about that either.

Comment: @SebastianC.: Took a look at `brother-lpr-drivers-extra`, and it indeed seems to include the LPR driver for DCP-150C. So, then, have you configured your system to use the printer?

Comment: Have many thanks for u effort to help me here Gunnar !!!  I realy apreciate it.  U see the thing is that I have installed the drivers into my system,  however if I try to print for example in Libre Office 4.3.3.2,  then it says : " Printer could not be started. Please check u Printer configurations. "  Now I've tried to disconnect my Printer and deinstall it in the Terminal ~ restart my PC and install the software again ~restart again and plug in my Printer.  Now the Printer is found. The Name is correct,  however I can't print.  Do u have a tipp ?

Comment: HiHiHi itś crazy Gunnar,  all of a sudden the Printer is working !!!  Thanks for u assistance I realy apeciate it !!!  Super I happy,  now my next task will be to solve the skype riddle.  Perhaps I will also get such GOOD HELP as I did from u Gunnar.  ;-) thanx a million.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you did not actually add a new printer to your system after installing the drivers.

Try installing the package first, and then open the "Printers" program and adding a new printer. Be sure to select the correct printer type.

Comment: Oh thank u for offering u help,  but my Printer is working fine now my next task is to figure out as to why my Skype isn't working.

Comment: Alright, it's highly likely that the information you need to get Skype working is already available online, so do a web search first before posting here.